# What should the $\mathfrak{sl}(3)$ Chebyshev polynomials be?

Tags: abstract-algebra, recurrence-relations, lie-algebras, chebyshev-polynomials

Consider $\mathfrak{sl}_2$ and its fundamental weight $\lambda_1$. The character of the simple representation $L(n\lambda_1)$ with highest weight $n\lambda_1$ is given by a polynomial in $x=\mathrm{ch}L(\lambda_1)$. Writing $P_n(x)=\mathrm{ch}L(n\lambda_1)$, we have a recurrence $P_n(x)=xP_{n-1}(x)-P_{n-2}$. The first few polynomials are $1,x,x^2-1,x^3-2x\dots$ These are actually the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind on the interval $[-2,2]$.

Consider the same question for $\mathfrak{sl}_3$, with simple roots $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$ and corresponding fundamental weights $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$. Let $x=\mathrm{ch}L(\lambda_1)$ and $y=\mathrm{ch}L(\lambda_2)$. Let $P_{m,n}(x,y)=\mathrm{ch}L(m\lambda_1+n\lambda_2)$.

> 1. What recurrence do the $P_{m,n}(x,y)$ satisfy?

Recall that the classical Chebyshev polynomials satisfy $\int_{-2}^2P_m(x)P_n(x)\sqrt{4-x^2}dx=\delta_{m,n}$.

> 2. Are the $P_{m, n}$ orthogonal in the way that the Chebyshev polynomials are orthogonal?

Comment: What do you mean by $chL(\lambda_k)$ ? Is your "ch" meaning "cosh" (hyperbolic cosine) ? Besides, what is the meaning of capital L ?

Comment: I think $\operatorname{ch}$ is just short for "character" and $L(\lambda)$ is the representation with highest weight $\lambda$?  Generally very confusing to read without any explanation of notation.

Comment: The *character* in this context is the generating function for the dimensions of the weight spaces for the representation: 
$$
\operatorname{ch} L = \sum_{\mu} (\dim L_\mu)\, e^\mu
$$

Comment: For example $P_{m,n}(x,y)=P_{m,0}(x,y)P_{0,n}(x,y)-P_{m-1,0}(x,y)P_{0,n-1}(x,y)$

Comment: Also $x^3-2$ is not a Chebyshev polynomial.  OP probably meant $x^3-2x$ instead.

Comment: @Leox That's true! Although that recursion does not determine $P_{m,0}$ or $P_{0,n}$. Did you realize this by looking at the expansion of the product of Schur polynomials $s_{(m)}s_{(n)^T}$?

Comment: @ Alvaro Martinez Of course

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

Try to prove that
$$
P_{m+1,n}(x,y)=x P_{m,n}(x,y)-P_{m,n-1}(x,y)-P_{m-1,n+1}(x,y)\\
P_{m,n+1}(x,y)=y P_{m,n}(x,y)-P_{m-1,n}(x,y)-P_{m+1,n-1}(x,y)
$$

and then try eliminate the terms $P_{m-1,n+1}(x,y)$ and $P_{m+1,n-1}(x,y).$

Comment: Actually those recurrences are more in the line of what I was going for, as they actually determine the polynomials $P_{m,n}$. Thanks! I will wait to see if someone has something to say about the orthogonality.

Comment: Also do these polynomials have a name?

Comment: Their name can be such - bivariate Chebyshev polynomials associated with the Lie algebra  $sl_3$  or $sl_3$-Chebyshev polynomials

Comment: About orthogonality of the polynomialas you may read in the paper  "Two-Variable Analogues of the Classical Orthogonal Polynomials Tom Koornwinder". But it is very strange orthogonality

Comment: Great, that's what I was looking for, thank you